# Loading an image in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm just starting to learn libGDX programming, and I found that there are two ways of loading images in this framework:

```
texture = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
```

and

```
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
```

I was just wondering if there is a difference between this two statement or are they the same.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting from the source code of Texture.java in LibGDX, they are internally the same thing.

```
public Texture (String internalPath) {
    this(Gdx.files.internal(internalPath));
}

public Texture (FileHandle file) {
    this(file, null, false);
}
```

you can find the source code here : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java

Comment: So they are the same, but the first statement is easier though

Comment: Yes, the first one is a convenience method.

Comment: and btw, if you are satisfied with the answer, I would be glad if you mark it as as such. Thanx.

Comment: Sure and sorry I forgot

Comment: +1 for digging into the source, which is often (unfortunately) the right way to resolve questions about libGDX

Comment: unfortunately, I agree with you. LibGDX is very powerful but I think the community support is little especially when it comes to documentation.  Even javadoc is not very descriptive

Comment: Btw, it is very easy to go into the source while you are using android studio, just ctrl+click on the method that you want to investigate. The built-in decompiler will open the corresponding method of that class and you can propagate inside the class to see what is going on.